# Oracle Mutating Tables - Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a trigger on a table that, whenever you insert a record, it generates a new record (IN A SEPARATE TABLE) from a mapping table. It also does this when you update a record, looking for any change in the contents of one field.

When this executes I get the dreaded error, ORA-04091: table SCHEMA.TABLE1 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it but I do not see how. I am not changing any data in the table that triggered the trigger.

NOTE: I tried the COMPOUND TRIGGER but can't seem to get that going. I'll spend more time on it if someone is able to tell me why the trigger above could possibly throw the mutating table error.

Thanks for any help!

````
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCHEMA.TRIGGER1
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT or UPDATE
ON SCHEMA.TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF updating THEN  
        IF (:old.TABLE1_FIELD1 != :new.TABLE1_FIELD1 
                OR (:old.TABLE1_FIELD1 is null and :new.TABLE1_FIELD1 is not null) 
                OR (:old.TABLE1_FIELD1 is not null and :new.TABLE1_FIELD1 is null)
                    AND (:new.TABLE1_FIELD1 != 0)
            ) 
        THEN
            -- DELETE ASSOCIATED RECORDS FIRST
            DELETE FROM TABLE2 
            WHERE TABLE1_ID_FIELD = :old.TABLE1_ID_FIELD;
            
            -- ADD IMT TAG
            INSERT INTO TABLE2(TABLE2.FK1, TABLE1_ID_FIELD)
            SELECT DISTINCT 1521 /* IMT */, r.TABLE1_ID_FIELD
            FROM TABLE3 m INNER JOIN TABLE1 r ON m.TABLE3.FK2 = r.TABLE1_FIELD1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from TABLE2 where TABLE2.FK1=1521 and TABLE1_ID_FIELD =r.TABLE1_ID_FIELD)  
                And TABLE1_FIELD1 <> 0
                And TABLE1_ID_FIELD = :old.TABLE1_ID_FIELD;

            -- ADD ALL OTHER TAGS BASED ON MAPPING TABLE
            INSERT INTO TABLE2(TABLE2.FK1, TABLE1_ID_FIELD)
            SELECT TABLE3.FK1, r.TABLE1_ID_FIELD
            FROM TABLE3 m INNER JOIN TABLE1 r ON m.TABLE3.FK2 = r.TABLE1_FIELD1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from TABLE2 where TABLE2.FK1=m.TABLE3.FK1 and TABLE1_ID_FIELD =r.TABLE1_ID_FIELD)
                And TABLE1_FIELD1 <> 0
                And TABLE1_ID_FIELD = :old.TABLE1_ID_FIELD; 
        END IF;
    ELSIF inserting THEN
        IF (:new.TABLE1_FIELD1 != 0) THEN
            -- ALWAYS HAVE THIS ASSOCIATION
            INSERT INTO TABLE2(TABLE2.FK1, TABLE1_ID_FIELD)
            SELECT DISTINCT 1521, r.TABLE1_ID_FIELD
            FROM TABLE3 m INNER JOIN TABLE1 r ON m.TABLE3.FK2 = r.TABLE1_FIELD1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from TABLE2 where TABLE2.FK1=1521 and TABLE1_ID_FIELD =r.TABLE1_ID_FIELD)  
                And TABLE1_FIELD1 <> 0
                And TABLE1_ID_FIELD = :new.TABLE1_ID_FIELD;

            -- ADD ALL OTHER ASSOCIATIONS BASED ON MAPPING TABLE
            INSERT INTO TABLE2(TABLE2.FK1, TABLE1_ID_FIELD)
            SELECT TABLE3.FK1, r.TABLE1_ID_FIELD
            FROM TABLE3 m INNER JOIN TABLE1 r ON m.TABLE3.FK2 = r.TABLE1_FIELD1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from TABLE2 where TABLE2.FK1=m.TABLE3.FK1 and TABLE1_ID_FIELD =r.TABLE1_ID_FIELD)
                And TABLE1_FIELD1 <> 0
                And TABLE1_ID_FIELD = :new.TABLE1_ID_FIELD; 
        END IF;
     END IF;
   END;```
````

Comment: You select `FROM TABLE3 m INNER JOIN TABLE1 r ON ...`

Comment: So I cannot select from the table even?

Comment: Correct.  The table is mutating (it is in an indeterminant state) so you cannot query it.  My guess is that you don't want to query it, you just want to use attributes from the `:new` pseudorecord but you haven't shown table definitions/ data/ expected results so I don't know that for sure.

Comment: Thank you - that's what I ended up doing. I used the :new pseudorecord. I appreciate the insight!